# Sieve vacation mail reply, copy to sent directory

Tags: sieve

I search how to make a copy of each mails send in reply by sieve vacation sieve script.

My actual script sive

```
require ["date","relational","vacation"];
# rule:[Avis d’absence]
if allof (currentdate :zone "+0100" :value "ge" "iso8601" "2024-02-27T08:00:00+01:00", currentdate :zone "+0200" :value "le" "iso8601" "2024-08-25T08:00:00+02:00")
{
    vacation :days 180 :subject "Vous venez de contacterxxxxxxx" text:
Bonjour,

xxxxxxxx
;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello, @DavidPostill how to add a rules to copy the mail sendend by sieve in autoreply in Sent directory ?

Comment: The question need to be in your post, not down here in the comments. Please visit the Help section and read through the Tour to familiarize yourself with this site. Then, come back and edit your question, giving a clear statement of your problem, your question, the research you've done, what you've tried, and any error messages or logs that may help.